# UINavigationBar horizontal gradient

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to set a horizontal gradient on a UINavigationBar. I've so far got it so that in portrait mode the gradient displays correctly by using the following code:

```
static internal class UINavigationControllerExtensions
{
    public static void SetBarDefaults(this UINavigationController controller)
    {
        controller.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage(UIImage.FromFile(IosConstants.ApplicationGradient));

        //Other setup stuff
    }
}
```

This extension method gets called on our first view and it sets it correctly for all the portrait views.

My problem occurs when the device is rotated. When this happens the gradient gets cut off at the width of the NavigationBar as if it is in portrait mode and then starts again resulting in a line of stark difference.

I've tried as an experiment waiting for a rotation event on a view controller then re-calling this method to try to re-draw the gradient but apparently that doesn't work either.

Does anyone know how I can get this to resize properly on rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that :

`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gardientImage"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

for ios 7 navigation bar height is 64px

Comment: I've actually already given this a go as well, however it results in the same problem with the image cutting off and then repeating at what would be the portrait width.

Comment: what is the dimensions of your image ?

Comment: Good call! It was indeed the image size. It wasn't wide enough hence the issues.